# I am having trouble calling my output method in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to use my methods inside the output method and then call the if statement so that it ask for name, age, then runs the output method with the users entered inputs. I am really stuck and have tried many things. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class javaMethods {

    private static Scanner s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        name();
        age();
        output(name(), age());
    }

    static String name() {
        s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter full name");
        String names = s.nextLine();
        String result = names;
        return result;

    }
    public static int age() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter age");
        String ages = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println(ages);
        return age();
    }
    public static void output(String name, int age) {

        if (age >= 50) {
            System.out.println("Hello " + name + "since you are " + age + "you are really old.");
        } else if (age <= 21) {
            System.out.println("Hello " + name + "since you are " + age + "you are really young.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Hello " + name + "since you are " + age + "you are doing just fine");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the answer helped and fixed your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark

Answer (score 0):

First point is that `name and age methods` return `string` and `integer`, so in your main method you have to save these data in 2 variables. Like this:

> String n = name();

> int a = age();

Second point is that the inputs of `output method` have to that 2 variables! NOT `the name of method`!

> output(n, a);

Try this one:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class javaMethods {

    private static Scanner s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String n = name();
        int a = age();
        output(n, a);
    }

    static String name() {
        s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter full name");
        String names = s.nextLine();
        return names;
    }

    public static int age() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter age");
        int ages = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(ages);
        return ages;
    }

    public static void output(String name, int age) {

        if (age >= 50) {
            System.out.println("Hello " + name + "since you are " + age + "you are really old.");
        } else if (age <= 21) {
            System.out.println("Hello " + name + "since you are " + age + "you are really young.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Hello " + name + "since you are " + age + "you are doing just fine");
        }
    }
}
```

Another point is that the type of `age` variable is `integer` NOT `string`!

Good Luck.